# c# schedule windows service for specific date(s)

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have seen a lot of posts to configure a windows service for daily/weekly etc schedules, but if I want a schedule that is not uniform, how do I manage that from a windows-service perspective? I have an app that I want to run at particular times. Running it at a uniform schedule wouldn't do me any good and just waste resources. Can I configure it by using some XML file, or windows service configuration?

Comment: wouldn't the Windows task scheduler be the best option for this? Just create a normal application and schedule it that way. A service really is not the best way to do this (except insofar as the task scheduler is itself a service)

Comment: The task scheduler is still a uniform scheduler, or a one-time scheduler. What I am looking for is some program that I can give a set of dates (non-uniform), and it will start up my app to run once for each of those dates.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options.

1. Take a look at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)
2. Use Windows scheduler.  Just have a different "schedule" for each date/time you need the app to run.
3. Write your own.

Comment: The only easy way I was looking at was just making a bunch of scheduled one-time tasks, so 2). I found some info about the AT command. But I don't know how to specify a date and time. How easy do you think it would be to accomplish 3)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that is something of a hybrid approach:

Create a text file that has the dates and times you want the program to run.  For example, it might contain:

```
2011-03-01
0100
0312
0815
0945
1340

2011-03-02
0220
...
```

Then, write your program that does whatever task it needs to do, and the last thing it does before exiting is read the file, find the next time that it needs to run, and schedules itself (by issuing an AT command, by calling [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx), or by calling the equivalent [Task Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions).

The Task Scheduler API is not for the timid.  I would suggest looking into a wrapper.  A search for "windows task scheduler C#" returns several.