# How to send scheduled email alerts using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, scheduled-tasks

I need to send emails notifications to the users, for this the user insert a date, this is stored in a Data Base (MS SQL) then my app should send an email alert in this date, how can I do this..??

I have read about windows services, and I tried to do one, but doesn't work, anybody can help me...??

I´m using asp.net, c# and MVC model

Comment: Why didn't your Windows service work?

Comment: I think OP's problem is how to compare the date, and in order to compare the date, how frequently, the service/scheduled task should do the check..

Comment: @verofairy, let me guess, you're one of those rare programmers who just *loves* it when your users comes back to you and, with no elaboration, complains that your program "doesn't work".

Comment: Dears: @PirateKitten: I tried to do the windows service but when I try to start it automatically stop, cause it isn't do anithing (it says a dialog box). @Bolu: exactly, this is my problem, I don`t know how to compare constantly the date. @Kirk: No, my app isn`t being used yet

Comment: @verofairy: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157828/c-sharp-schedule-windows-service-for-specific-dates

Answer (score 1):

you can create console application which capable of fetching user details and notification date from the database and send notification mails.

You can use windows scheduled task to run this `exe` file.

> e.g. Run this scheduled task on every day on given time. your
>   application will send mails to users if any notifications need to be
>   sent on that day.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the System.Net.Mail namespace for .NET generated mail:

```
MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();

Message.Sender = new MailAddress(OutgoingEmailAddress, OutgoingEmailDisplayName);
Message.From = new MailAddress(OutgoingEmailAddress, OutgoingEmailDisplayName);
Message.Subject = "The subject of your email";
Message.Priority = MailPriority.High;

// Add Recipients                    
foreach (string Email in (SuccessRecipientList.Split(';')))
     Message.To.Add(Email);

// Set Body                
Message.Body = Body;

// Send the Email
SmtpClient EmailClient = new SmtpClient("smtpServerNameHere");
EmailClient.Send(Message);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but my real problem is send it in a specific date, that should be picked of a Data Base. For example, a user inserts his birthday date, and I need that my app sends him an congratulation email in his birthday day.